# Ordenar un Dictionary string alfabeticámente LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, linq

tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una variable `data` del tipo `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>` con los siguientes datos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual necesito mantener el mismo tipo de datos, pero, ordenado por VENDEDOR alfabéticamnte

Lo estoy haciendo con linq, pero, no he dado resultado. También probé con la función `Sort();`, pero sin resultados. Si alguien me podría orientar o alguna otra función se lo agradecería .

Aqui dejo mi codigo :

```
var data = ventas.ComisionesLocalFull(Empresa, anio, mes, sucursales);

IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> resp = new <Dictionary<string, string>> ;

resp = from x in data 
       orderby x.Value.Count.VENDEDOR 
       ascending select x ;
```

Comment: noto que tienes x.Value.Count.VENDEDOR estas seguro que estas accediendo al nombre?

Comment: En realidad no, si accedo la variable resp me llega vacía. Solo me iba guiando por el debug.

Comment: probaste sin el order by? es decir, from x in data select x, solo como para ver que llegue un arreglo de items

Comment: porque usas este tipo de dato `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>` que no representa nada? porque no defines una clase con propiedades donde puedas asignar los datos. Los datos estan completamente desasociados no vas a poder ordenar como lo planteas porque solo son listas de key-value

Comment: Lo suyo es que tengas un objeto tipo VENTA con sus propiedades LOCAL, VENDENDOR, RUT,DIAS... y que luego lo ordenes.